# Make logging output pretty when using backslash in string for Python PEP 8?

Tags: python, logging, pep8

I have a CLI script which uses the logging module to print to screen and file. Is it possible to make ouput *look better* when breaking long lines for PEP8 using `\`?

```
logger.warning("SKIPPED File: '%s'; \
    MyFunc() returned no results."
    % (dir_file, ))

                               # You have to scroll to see the result --> 
WARNING----SKIPPED File: 'test-filetypes/client-somefile.txt';                            MyFunc() returned no results.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use implicit string concatenation:

```
logger.warning(
    "SKIPPED File: '%s'; "
    "MyFunc() returned no results.",
    dir_file,
)
```

*Note:* I've fixed one other detail here - you shouldn't eagerly format your log strings. Just pass the template variable(s) along as arguments in the logging call.

Answer (score 1):

strings right next to each automatically get appended so

```
logger.warning("SKIPPED File: '%s'; " \
   "MyFunc() returned no results."
    % (dir_file, ))
```

Should get you what you want.